# CG drawing in UIView to use as UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I am attempting to create a custom back button for UINavigationbar.

I know that I can use `backButtonBackgroundImageForState:barMetrics:` to set an image.

My problem is that I don't what to have to use an image file. I would rather draw the back button in code.

My question is can I subclass a UIView, override the drawrec: to draw a back button, then use that UIView as an image in `backButtonBackgroundImageForState:barMetrics`:

I'm thinking that it would go something like:

```
UIImage * backButtonImage = // somehow get image from my subclassed UIView;

backButtonImage = [backButtonImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 15.0 topCapHeight: 30.0];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage: backButtonImage forState: UIControlStateNormal barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Is this even the best way to be going about this? Or should I just suck it up and create an image in photoshop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bitmap image context using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, without making a subclass of `UIView` and overriding `drawRect:`.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(80, 30), NO, 0);
// drawing code here
// Use UIKit functions and objects
// or use CoreGraphics functions on UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```