# Custom UINavigationBar Drawing Empty

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, uinavigationbar

This is probably something very easy and stupid of me but I have a custom `UINavigationBar` that customized it with core graphics in the `drawrect` method.  I use it multiple times throughout my app and all but two instances work fine.  The two instances when loaded into view are rendering black when they should be a gray gradient.  The `drawrect` method is being called but for some reason they are being presented black in the view.

### These are the IB settings I have for the UINavigationBar

[image]

### And the settings I have for the parent UIVIew

[image]

If theres any other information I can provide to make this easier please just let me know.  Thanks a lot for anyone that can help.

Comment: Is this a subclass of UINavigationBar, or are you overriding drawRect in a category? why aren't you using the UIAppearance methods?

Comment: I'm subclassing UInavigationBar

Comment: AFAIK, UI Appearance can only use UIImage instances to customize appearance for navigation bars. The only way I can think of to use custom drawing in conjunction with UI Appearance would be to do the drawing into an image context and then use the resulting UIImage. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864223/cg-drawing-in-uiview-to-use-as-uiimage

Comment: I actually went ahead and used the UIAppearance methods like jrturton suggested.  Thanks a lot guys